# Return to Page where form was opened from

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Asp.Net page which has some fields as readonly (textboxes, Grid etc). When user click on the edit button, a new Asp.Net page is opened like a form like this:

```
<a class="iframe2 cboxElement" href='<%# ResolveUrl("./ProjectMainPageEdit.aspx?editspid="+ Eval("id").ToString() ) %>'>
</a>
```

When user is done with editing and presses "Update" button, I want this form to close and return to the original page from where this was opened.
I tried `Response.Redirect("")` but this opens the page in the same form.
If I click close button the form, it does return me to the page I want to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an iframe to load this form, so if you do a `response.redirect("");` it'll redirect INSIDE the iframe, not outside of it (parent page).

Supposing that you're using an iframe I would call a javascript like this:

```
 var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, this.GetType(), "redirectFunction", "window.top.location.href = '" + ResolveUrl() + "'", true);
```